# Extracting HTML tags with specific attributes in GREL

Tags: html, xml, jsoup, openrefine, grel

I can easily extract a tag the first time it appears

```
<skos:prefLabel> Espitaleta, Lina </skos:prefLabel>
```

And *every* time it appears:

```
<skos:prefLabel> Espitaleta, Lina </skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en-US"> Espitaleta, Lina </skos:prefLabel>
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr-FR"> Lina Espitaleta </skos:prefLabel>
```

But how do I extract only those tags with a specific attribute?

```
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fr-FR"> Lina Espitaleta </skos:prefLabel>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, based on your example, that you are looking for a specific attribute value, not just an attribute.

The GREL implementation uses JSoup internally, so you want to look at their [selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to figure out how to do this. Something along the lines of:

```
value.parseHtml().select(your selector here)
```

should get you what you want. There is a slight nuance in dealing with namespaces which are handled differently in the tag name vs attribute name, so you'll want something like:

```
value.parseHtml().select('skos|prefLabel[xml:lang="fr-FR"]')
```

If you really did mean attribute, not attribute value, you can simplify it to just:

```
value.parseHtml().select('skos|prefLabel[xml:lang]')
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I did mean attribute value.  This works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! Please upvote and accept the answer if it met your needs.